# How to get latest chromium code, and compile it in debug mode?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, chromium

How to get latest chromium code, and compile it in debug mode? I am using ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a Chromium package with debug mode enabled, you can easily install `chromium-browser-dbg` from the [Chromium PPA](https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily/+archive/ppa).

Answer (score 1):

Checking out from SVN can take a long time.

You can download the source tarball in
http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code

The link also contains instructions of how to build code under Ubuntu.